# link php file to a view all button in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In `category.php` page I am listing posts by 
`sub-categries`, and which sub-category contains more than 3 posts
I will display a `VIEW ALL` button to go to `view-all.php` page.
In my wordpress themes folder I have a page named "`view-all.php`" to view all posts under a particular sub-category.
But I don't understand how do I link that VIEW ALL button to the `view-all.php` page with some `parameter`. Please help me with your suggestion as I am a beginner in wordpress
Thank you

This is `category.php`

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
<?php
// get category ID of particular category
$current_category = single_cat_title("", false);
$category_id = get_cat_ID($current_category);
// end getting category ID

// Get the name of sub-category
$categories =  get_categories('child_of='.$category_id);
foreach  ($categories as $category) {

// Display the sub category information using $category values like $category->cat_name
echo "<div class='sub-category-wrapper'>";
echo '<h3 class="sub-cat-name">&raquo; '.$category->name.'</h3>';

// get number of posts under this sub-category
$total_posts = $category->count;

// Make a loop to display post link which are in this sub category
foreach (get_posts( array(
'category' => $category->term_id,
'orderby' => 'date',
'order'   => 'DESC',
'numberposts' => 3,   // limit number of posts
) ) as $post) {
setup_postdata( $post );
echo "<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 post-link'>";
echo '<h4 class="title"><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h4>';
echo '<div class="post-thumb">';
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">';
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
the_post_thumbnail();
}
echo '</a>';
echo '</div>';
echo "</div>";
}

if( $total_posts > 3 )
{   ?>
<a href="#">View all</a>
<?php   }
echo "</div>";  /* sub-category-wrapper */

}
?>
</div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Explain it a little bit with code then we may help..

Comment: I have a view-all.php file in my themes folder, I want to link it in category.php page with a button named "VIEW ALL" 
how can I do that.?

Comment: kindly mention this part of code in your question

Comment: edit the question and place the code viewall button in category.php

Comment: I have updated my question with complete script of category.php, please have a look at it

Comment: check the answer if it works then mark the answer correct

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="view-all">View all</a>
```

simply change this line in the above code if they are located in one directory